# If a subset of topological space $X$ meets each dense set in $X$ then its interior is not empty

Tags: general-topology

This is an exercise from Bourbaki's *General Topology*:

> Show that a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ meets each dense subset of $X$ if and only if the interior of $A$ is not empty.

The sufficiency part is obvious because every non-empty open set $A$ of $X$ meets every dense set in $X$.
And I'm struggling with the necessity part.

Comment: If $A$ has empty interior then $A^{c}$ is dense and $A$ does not meet this dense set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the interior of $A$ is empty. Consider $B=X\setminus A$. Certainly $A$ and $B$ don't meet. Is $B$ dense? If an open subset of $X$ does not meet $B$, it's contained
in $A$ and so in $A^\circ$, etc.